# Bash - Rename part of Filenames

Tags: bash, filenames, rename

i need , some help , with my mini-script , to Fix , Spanish Filename with ISO_8859-1 and/or with part of names like `"&#00243"`

The Script its there : http://www.pastebin.com/vT5Z2BqE

Yesterday with a 3 Things , are working , i add more , and dont work anymore , i dont understand why .

Look , if i use that command in a "Bash Shell" / "Gnome-Terminal" like :

```
inukaze@Inukaze:~$ cd Filenames_to_fix 
inukaze@Inukaze:~/Filenames_to_fix$ 
inukaze@Inukaze:~/Filenames_to_fix$ expresion='&#00176'
inukaze@Inukaze:~/Filenames_to_fix$ sustituto='°'
inukaze@Inukaze:~/Filenames_to_fix$ ls *$expresion*
01 - La Espada del Augurio &#00176.avi

inukaze@Inukaze:~/Filenames_to_fix$ for i in $( ls $expresion ); do

> orig=$i
> dest=$(echo $i | sed -e "s/$expresion/$sustituto/")
> mv $orig $dest
> done

mv: no se puede efectuar stat' sobre «01»: No existe el fichero o el directorio 
mv: no se puede efectuarstat' sobre «-»: No existe el fichero o el directorio 
mv: no se puede efectuar stat' sobre «La»: No existe el fichero o el directorio 
mv: no se puede efectuarstat' sobre «Espada»: No existe el fichero o el directorio 
mv: no se puede efectuar stat' sobre «del»: No existe el fichero o el directorio 
mv: no se puede efectuarstat' sobre «Augurio»: No existe el fichero o el directorio 
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre «°»: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

I need , the change of part of filename "°" for "ª" , for example
Someone / somebody , can explain why this error , and how to fix it ???

I dont wanna interactive mode , and dont wanna replace "extension" i wanna "rename" the bad part of filename , with the "Good" character in its place :D.

Thank you for readme , and sorry my bad english , thank you for any help can you give me with this script

Answer (score 1):

You do not quote $orig and $dest and that causes problems when the filename contains spaces (mv is given the file name as several separate arguments (which is why it prints several error messages with parts of the file name)). Try to use

```
mv "$orig" "$dest"
```

instead.

Comment: Also the loop driver is wrong - you want `for i in *$expresion*; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

The for loop uses whitespace as a delimiter. Since your file name contains whitespace, you will need to change what you are using as a delimiter.

Here is the equivalent using `find` and `while`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*${expresion}*" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    orig="$file"
    dest=$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s/${expresion}/${sustituto}/")
    mv "$orig" "$dest"
done
```

HOWEVER, a better solution is probably to use the `rename` command:

```
rename $expresion $sustituto *${expresion}*
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command available?

```
rename  $expresion $sustituto *$expresion*
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion . but i dont know if "rename" its available in all distro , like "mv"

Comment: The Mini-Script its Finished , i hope this works , for any linux user , with any Linux Distro . you can see all code in >> " http://pastebin.com/vT5Z2BqE " <<